# Spark Thrift Server "Address already in use java.net.BindException: Address already in use"

Tags: linux, hadoop, apache-spark, ambari

When I run/start the thrift server

```
su spark

./sbin/start-thriftserver.sh
```

or

```
./sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --master yarn-client --executor-memory 512m --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=100015
```

from /var/log/spark2/

we get

```
 WARN AbstractLifeCycle: FAILED ServerConnector@1fc793c2{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:4040}: java.net.BindException: Address already in use java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried starting with different free port for thrift ?

Comment: please show me how

Comment: now I have diff error - ERROR SparkContext: Failed to add file:/tmp/hsperfdata_spark/JDBC/ODBC to Spark environment
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Jar /tmp/hsperfdata_spark/JDBC/ODBC not found

Comment: it means either the jdbc/odbc library not exists at all or spark environmental configs not set properly

Comment: how to verify jdbc lib not exist?